# How would I write a script to organize a list into a specific table-format?

Tags: text, formatting

I have a list of approximately 4,000-odd ancient Chinese proverbs I would like to import into Pleco (a Chinese dictionary app) for flashcards. However, Pleco needs them in a specific format (a table separated by tabs) and to do so manually would take forever.

Any idea how I would implement a script to automatically format the list?

e.g.

```
Ài fàn yǒu fàn; xī yī yǒu yī.
爱饭有饭, 惜衣有衣。
愛飯有飯, 惜衣有衣。
[Those who] treasure [their] food [will always] have food [and those who] take care of [their] clothing [will always] have clothes [to wear]. 
[An admonition to thrift; see also bùyī nuǎn below.]
        CLOTHING FOOD THRIFT
[A2]
Ái gǒu yǎo de rén bù dōu shì zéi.
挨狗咬的人不都是贼。
挨狗咬的人不都是賊。
(lit) Not all who are bitten by dogs are thieves. 
(fig) One should not make judgments based on superficial appearances. Things are not always as they (first) appear.
        APPEARANCES JUDGMENTS
[A3]
Áiguo shé yǎo, jiàn shàn pǎo.
挨过蛇咬, 见鳝跑。
挨過蛇咬, 見鱔跑。
(lit) [One who has been] bitten by a snake [at the] sight [of an] eel [will] run away. 
(fig) “Once bitten, twice shy.” 
[See also yīzhāo bèi shé yǎo below.]
        EXPERIENCE LEARNING
```

into:

```
爱饭有饭, 惜衣有衣  愛飯有飯, 惜衣有衣      [Those who] treasure [their] food [will always] have food [and those who] take care of [their] clothing [will always] have clothes [to wear]. 
[An admonition to thrift; see also bùyī nuǎn below.]

挨狗咬的人不都是贼。  挨狗咬的人不都是賊。      (lit) Not all who are bitten by dogs are thieves. 
(fig) One should not make judgments based on superficial appearances. Things are not always as they (first) appear.

挨过蛇咬, 见鳝跑。  挨過蛇咬, 見鱔跑。      (lit) [One who has been] bitten by a snake [at the] sight [of an] eel [will] run away. 
(fig) “Once bitten, twice shy.” 
[See also yīzhāo bèi shé yǎo below.]
```

It needs to be in the form: Simplified characters TAB Traditional characters TAB TAB Definition

Please leave out the Pinyin (e.g. Ài fàn yǒu fàn; xī yī yǒu yī.), the identifier (e.g. [A1], [A2]) and the last line with the topics (e.g. CLOTHING FOOD THRIFT)

Further down the code the lines will not always be exact. Sometimes there will be more or less lines per proverb.

Thank you all so much! StackOverflow has been a huge help to me in my coding adventures.